# Как сделать ответ на ложное(неверное) сообщение пользователя?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Как сделать так, чтобы в случае неправильного ответа(нет такого слова в мозгах бота),он выдавал типо я тебя не понял. Вот кусок кода,и если она напишет Трема Пифгора бот написал я тебя не понял и вернул обратно в меню поиска/продолжил поиск сам.

```
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess2)
        elif message.text == 'Связь с разработчиком':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess3)
        elif message.text == 'Начать поиск:':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess4)
        elif message.text in ['Таблица умножения', 'Табличка умножения','таблица умножения','табличка множения']:
            photo1 = open('3ebc0dfa867e344cf30d81409cfd7558.jpg', 'rb')
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
        elif message.text in ['теорема пифагора','Теорема Пифагора','теорема Пифагора']:
            photo1 = open('maxresdefault.jpg', 'rb')
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сойдет?

```
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess2)
        elif message.text == 'Связь с разработчиком':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess3)
        elif message.text == 'Начать поиск:':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess4)
        elif message.text in ['Таблица умножения', 'Табличка умножения','таблица умножения','табличка множения']:
            photo1 = open('3ebc0dfa867e344cf30d81409cfd7558.jpg', 'rb')
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
        elif message.text in ['теорема пифагора','Теорема Пифагора','теорема Пифагора']:
            photo1 = open('maxresdefault.jpg', 'rb')
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "ШО за бред ты написал, а?")
```

Comment: респект(лично думал что не через else надо делать)